# Finding the Range

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, range

Hi so for homework I have to type up a program where it will accept two numbers. If one of the numbers on the left is smaller than the one on the right, it will increase. If the second number is smaller than the first number than it will decrease. If both numbers are the same then it should stay the same. Here the program I had written so far:

```
def range_of_numbers (number1, number2):
    if (number2 > number1):
        for num1 in range (1):
            print (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 )
    elif (number1 > number2):
        for num2 in range (1):
            print (19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11)
    else:
        print (42)
```

The sample calls are: 
range_of _numbers (2, 8)
range_of_numbers (18, 11)
range_of_numbers (42, 42)
I got two of them right, but the last one keeps getting the wrong output and i dont know what wrong or where the mistake to fix it.

Comment: So you have to return hard-coded values?

Comment: _'If both numbers are the same then it should stay the same'_ I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: Yeah the values that were given, i have to return them. So i have to type a print statement that shows the numbers going up, one going down, and the last one that just the same

Comment: basically for the sample it says 45, 45. Since these two are the same, the print statement has to be the same. However, if it came out like 2, 8, the number on the left is smaller than the one on the right, so it gonna increase going up. If it was the opposite (8, 2), the number is gonna decrease and go down.

Comment: @ChristianLLanos What are your expected outputs for (2, 8), (18, 11) and (42, 42)? Which part of my answer's output is wrong?

Comment: the answer output that wrong is the (42,42)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, what you're doing with your first two cases is kind of "cheating" and is what's known as "hardcoding" results. You're not writing a function to perform the task but instead you're just printing the answers you know you should be seeing.

Ironically though, you're pretty close here.

This should do what you want:

```
def range_of_numbers (num1, num2):
    if(num1 < num2):
        for i in range(num2-num1 +1):
            print(num1+i)
    elif(num1 > num2):
        for i in range(num1-num2 +1):
            print(num1-i)
    else:
        print(num1)
```

if either num1 or num 2 is greater, we find the difference and make a for loop of that size (+1 since we're 0 indexed and we want to include both ends here). Then we either count up or count down, depending on which is higher.

Comment: Can you say what it is that isn't working please? What result are you expecting that you aren't getting? I do believe the code above does what you asked for in your original question. Please confirm you're asking your question properly

Comment: so the range isn't working as it should, the response I'm getting back for the first on (2, 8) is giving me 0 at the start when it shouldnt. It similar to the second one also (18, 11). It starting at 11 when it shouldnt be.

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly?? I'm running the exact same code and I'm getting the results you asked for.

Comment: yup copied the whole thing

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than to start a new file and try again. I'm not getting the results you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

Use 1 or -1 as steps in your range:

```
def range_of_numbers(a, b):
  if (a == b):
    print("same") 
  else:
    print(*list(range(a, b, (1 if a<b else -1))))
```

Test it:

```
range_of_numbers(2, 8)
range_of_numbers(18, 11)
range_of_numbers(42, 42)
```

Sure enough you get the desired output:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7
18 17 16 15 14 13 12
same
```